# Python:  parse Text File and Show as a Graph

Tags: python, parsing, graph

I have text files that are in this format:

```
   BFrame.make()
      Frame.make_bbox()
         BBox.__init__(arg1=x, arg2=y, arg3=z)
         : None
         BBox.make()
           BBox.chk_pre()
           : None
         : (1,1,2,2)
      : None
      ExConfig.__init__(filename=None)
        ExConfig.setParam()
            ExConfig.setfromKey(AUTO=[0.0, 0.0])
                 ExConfig.setFromList([('PHOT', [2.5, 3.5]), ('BV', [0.0, 0.0])])
                 : None
            : None
        : [returns a list of paramaters]
        ExConfig.getKwList()
            : [('A_THR', 3.0), ('B_THICK', 24),]
      : None
    etc..
   :Frame
```

What you see above is a call hierarchy.

The indents show which methods have been called or are calling.

Any lines that begins with ':' shows a return value of a method.

My problem is how to parse the text files and and represent this as a call hierarchy tree where each node is a method called. We attach attributes to each Node which are the args passed to that method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need a real parser here, since this is not a trivial format.

Many methods for writing parsers in Python exist. See, for example, [PLY](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/&rct=j&q=ply&ei=lsK_TbnONMPAswbBoIHDBQ&usg=AFQjCNHv-eylAV812hDOEVG2GLTa0AOZyA&cad=rja). Another is [PyParsing](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBgQFjAA&url=http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/&rct=j&q=pyparsing&ei=78K_TZzTHc_Lsgap-_nCBQ&usg=AFQjCNHYfzwvzIxYKcHuYSR5TCAIrvtEqw&cad=rja).

Alternatively, maybe [Python Call Graph](http://pycallgraph.slowchop.com/) is what you really need?

Comment: Something similar to pyCallGraph but for specific classes/methods. Our logging is done during run-time so called methods called are logged.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my shot at this:

```
a = """BFrame.make()
      Frame.make_bbox()
         BBox.__init__(arg1=x, arg2=y, arg3=z)
         : None
         BBox.make()
           BBox.chk_pre()
           : None
         : (1,1,2,2)
      : None
      ExConfig.__init__(filename=None)
        ExConfig.setParam()
            ExConfig.setfromKey(AUTO=[0.0, 0.0])
                 ExConfig.setFromList([('PHOT', [2.5, 3.5]), ('BV', [0.0, 0.0])])
                 : None
            : None
        : [returns a list of paramaters]
        ExConfig.getKwList()
            : [('A_THR', 3.0), ('B_THICK', 24),]
      : None
   :Frame"""

b = [ line.strip() for line in a.split("\n") ]

stck1 = []
stck2 = []

while b:
    add_v = b.pop(0)
    if add_v[0] != ':':
        stck1.append(add_v)
    else:
        if stck2:
            mx = max([x[0] for x in stck2])
        else:
            mx = 0
        if len(stck1) < mx:
            calls = []
            while stck2 and stck2[-1][0] == mx:            
                calls.append(stck2.pop())
            stck2.append([len(stck1), stck1.pop(), add_v, calls[::-1]])
        else:
            stck2.append([len(stck1), stck1.pop(), add_v])
```

which gives you this:

```
>>> pprint.pprint(stck2, width=5)
[[1,
  'BFrame.make()',
  ':Frame',
  [[2,
    'Frame.make_bbox()',
    ': None',
    [[3,
      'BBox.__init__(arg1=x, arg2=y, arg3=z)',
      ': None'],
     [3,
      'BBox.make()',
      ': (1,1,2,2)',
      [[4,
        'BBox.chk_pre()',
        ': None']]]]],
   [2,
    'ExConfig.__init__(filename=None)',
    ': None',
    [[3,
      'ExConfig.setParam()',
      ': [returns a list of paramaters]',
      [[4,
        'ExConfig.setfromKey(AUTO=[0.0, 0.0])',
        ': None',
        [[5,
          "ExConfig.setFromList([('PHOT', [2.5, 3.5]), ('BV', [0.0, 0.0])])",
          ': None']]]]],
     [3,
      'ExConfig.getKwList()',
      ": [('A_THR', 3.0), ('B_THICK', 24),]"]]]]]]
>>>
```

Nested `[ hierarchy_level, call, result, children_calls ]`, where children are structured the same as their parents.

one way to format:

```
>>> def pretty(X):
...     if len(X)==4:
...         print '\t'*X[0], X[1], 'returns', X[2]
...         print '\t'*X[0], 'children:'
...         for child in X[3]:
...             pretty(child)
...     else:
...         print '\t'*X[0], X[1], 'returns', X[2]
...         print '\t'*X[0], 'no children'
... 
>>> pretty(stck2[0])
    BFrame.make() returns :Frame
    children:
        Frame.make_bbox() returns : None
        children:
            BBox.__init__(arg1=x, arg2=y, arg3=z) returns : None
            no children
            BBox.make() returns : (1,1,2,2)
            children:
                BBox.chk_pre() returns : None
                no children
        ExConfig.__init__(filename=None) returns : None
        children:
            ExConfig.setParam() returns : [returns a list of paramaters]
            children:
                ExConfig.setfromKey(AUTO=[0.0, 0.0]) returns : None
                children:
                    ExConfig.setFromList([('PHOT', [2.5, 3.5]), ('BV', [0.0, 0.0])]) returns : None
                    no children
            ExConfig.getKwList() returns : [('A_THR', 3.0), ('B_THICK', 24),]
            no children
>>>
```